# Japanese Characters on Magento PDF

Tags: php, magento, pdf, fonts

I have got a few invoices in Magento which have Japanese characters in the address.  When I print the invoices these characters don't print correctly.

I got around this by changing the font to Arial Unicode in abstract.php.  The problem is this makes the invoice file huge (more than 10mb).

Is there another small font I could use which would display both Japanese and English characters correctly?

Comment: Which pdf library are you using ?

Comment: Zend_Pdf is used in magento

Answer (score 0):

Please use font `cid0jp`, it can probably solve your problem.