# Generating invoice PDF with special characters , Magento 1.9.1

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework, e-commerce, magento-1.9

I'm using Magento CE - 1.9.1  and i am facing this problem , when a invoice is generated a box appears in the invoice, where it should have a currency, I'm using INR ( rupee) in the invoice. Ive tired changing symbols and text in  the `Root.xml`, found in `zend/locale/data`, but nothing changes.

Am i editing the right file or is this some other issue.

Link to image of the error- https://i.stack.imgur.com/fv7L7.jpg

Comment: This looks like problem about generating pdf in Your application. I would edit Your question to help people to find it. I think the title "Generating PDF with special characters in Magneto" would be better. You can look at this question too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14379626/japanese-characters-on-magento-pdf

Comment: Yup i saw this article before writing this question, though im not sure if its a font missing or some thing else., is there any other way to edit it and check.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an encoding issue, are you using UTF-8? Maybe fiddeling with that might solve the issue.

Comment: hi , Sorry for this late reply - yes im using -  UTF-8 Unicode  - is there any other solutions ..??